# p implies q statement means that if p is true, q also has to be true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I don't understand this statement.  Looking at the truth table,

if p is false, the statement is always true.

if p is true and q is true, the statement is true.

if p is true and q is false, the statement is false.

So why does p implies q mean that if p is true, q has to be true? What about these other cases?

Comment: What else would you expect imply to mean..?

Comment: I would expect the statement to return a boolean value based off of the values of p, q.  However, it does not return a value . It simply states that if p is true, so must q.  However, there exists a scenario where p is true and q is false.  This violates their statement.  How does this work?

Comment: Actually, $p \Rightarrow q$ is a short notation for $q \vee \neg p$.

Comment: So how is this not returning a boolean value - that is just what the truth table tells you?

Comment: In some contexts, it's possible to assign a boolean value to it. In other contexts, you keep on with the idea that "if p, then q".

Comment: You may prefer the intuitionistic version of $\to$. In [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), $p\to q$ is *not* equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$. Instead, it means that you have a method which, given a proof of $p$, can transform it into a proof of $q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  This can be seen as a way of explaining modus ponens with which you may be more familiar:

If we know $p$ implies $q$ (is true), and $p$ happens to be true, then $q$ must be true:

$$p \rightarrow q$$
$$p$$
$$\therefore q$$

$p \rightarrow q,$  *by itself*, tells us *nothing* about the truth value of $q$. IF $p\rightarrow q$ is true we know that either $p$ is false, or $q$ is true, or both, which is nicely expressed as follows: $$(p \rightarrow q) \iff (\lnot p \lor q)$$